# replacing one processes esp value with other , to get a local variable

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel

I am trying to copy a current running process esp value to another processes esp, running on another terminal.

I am getting a segmentation fault.

But I can't figure out the reason correctly as I am using inline assembly.

p1.c

```
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int b =8;
    unsigned int esp =0;
    asm("mov %%esp,%0":"=r"(esp)::);
    printf("esp:[%x] \n",esp);
    while(1);
}
```

P2.c

```
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int espoth=0;
    asm("mov 0xbfda8008,%%esp"::);
}
```

First I ran `p1.c` which gave me `0xbfda8008` current stack pointer.
Then I used it in `p2.c` which gave me `Segmentation fault`.

I am just writing a value into esp. Why am I getting this fault ?
Need a little hint... ;-(

Comment: And why would the stack pointer of the first process be valid in the second process..?

Comment: thanks,thats true its not valid and what i am trying to do is not correct.
when there is first context switch all registers of first will be saved that doesn't means its stack (the variables) in it collapsed.
if there is second context switch p1 registres values will be preserved and the stack has to continue.
So,i feel that address must exist.Also since every process has its own (virtual to physical mapping) this address may be invalid.
but i am not accessing that address i am just writing that value to esp and getting error.Plz correct me wherever i am wrong !  @Michael

Comment: You are assuming that esp contains a pointer to an absolute memory location.  However, it doesn't.  When you have assembler instruction that accesses memory, what actually happens is the cpu (transparently) turns that memory address into the actual memory location, using an internal table associated with your process.  So every process can access (what it thinks of as) the same address, but since every process has its own mapping from address space to actual memory, they will all be different locations.  Once you understand how this works, you will understand virtual memory.

Comment: I'm not an expert at AT&T syntax inline assembly, but doesn't `mov 0xbfda8008,%%esp` mean `mov esp, [0xbfda8008]`. If you just wanted `mov esp, 0xbfda8008` I think you should prefix the immediate with a `$`. But even if you didn't get a segmentation fault at the `mov` instruction, you'll most likely get one soon afterwards when you attempt to use the stack after you've moved the stack pointer to some random location.

Comment: I got it ,my syntax was wrong @ Michael and @David Wohlerd thanks for the hint i should have thought a/c tha instruction  cpu will turn that memory address into the actual memory location... :-) its awsm

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as expected. The memory for each process is isolated from the other processes, and the memory-map each process sees is virtual. So even if two processes both might have memory available at the same address, it does not mean that the actual physical memory is the same.

This is what separates "modern" operating systems and hardware from the "old" ones. You can search about "mmu", "memory protection unit" and "virtual memory" on your favorite search engine.

Your idea would work if playing in good old MS-DOS for instance that did not use the MMU (unless playing with protected mode programs using for instance DOS4GW, GO32-V2)